# colspan screwing up css asp.net table

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, html-table

I created a table to organize my items on a page. The page is an edit page for a property.
I used colspan to expand rows and put a textbox within rows and set the textbox wdith to 100%, However, the textbox width still only takes the space of 1 column not 3 columns like I expected here is the code

```
 <table align="left" style="width: 100%; float: left" class="FormFormatTable">

    <tr>
        <td style="width: 10%; height: 60px">Alert Name</td>
        <td colspan="3" style=" ">
            <asp:TextBox CssClass="inputBoxes" ID="txtBox_alertName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 10%; height: 60px;">Alert</td>
        <td style="height: 60px; ">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_AlertTime" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">After</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Immediately</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 60px; ">
            <input id="demo_vertical0" type="number"/></td>
        <td style="height: 60px">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>Seconds</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Minutes</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Hours</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 10%">Severity</td>
        <td style=" height: 60px"" >
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Severity" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">After</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Immediately</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td style="">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:60px">
        <td style="width: 10%">Receipients</td>
        <td colspan="3" style="">
            <asp:TextBox CssClass="inputBoxes" ID="txtBox_Receipients" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:60px">
        <td style="width: 10%">Subject Title</td>
        <td colspan="3" style="">
            <asp:TextBox CssClass="inputBoxes" ID="txtBox_SubjectTitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:60px">
        <td style="width: 10%">Alert Messsage</td>
        <td colspan="3" style="">
            <asp:TextBox CssClass="inputBoxes" ID="txtBox_AlertMessage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:60px">
        <td style="width: 10%; ">Notification Window</td>
        <td style=" ">
            <asp:TextBox CssClass="inputBoxes"  ID="txtBox_NotificationWindow" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style=" "></td>
        <td style="height: 60px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:60px">
        <td style="width: 10%; ">Notification Frequency</td>
        <td style=" ">
            <input id="demo_vertical" type="number"/>
        </td>
        <td style=" "></td>
        <td style="height: 60px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:60px">
        <td style="width: 10%">Fields to Display in Details</td>
        <td colspan="3" style="">
            <asp:TextBox CssClass="inputBoxes" ID="txtBox_SubjectTitle3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css is simple just this

```
.inputBoxes {
    width: 100%;
}
```

why is this?

a screenshot of my page on my computer 
[image]

Comment: Please could you create a JS fiddle demonstrating the problem and/or the generated html.

Comment: Your very first statement `I created a table to organize my items on a page.` is already not recommended... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Comment: strange it works in JS fiddle this link when I paste in the direct html generated however it doesn't work when I compile and run I have the website posted here http://testingnan.azurewebsites.net/editcontent

however if I test it in js fiddle using t he code from view source at the webpage and add in the css at this link IT WORKS WHYYY???????????? JS fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/tw02j22t/

Comment: Does the CSS class `FormFormatTable` contain anything that manipulates the rows and columns?

Comment: no I deleted that css already but why does it renders different from JS fiddle and the actual page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you HTML 
the Alert Name , Receipients ,Subject Title ,Alert Messsage ,Fields to Display in Details TextBoxs take 3 columns .

Notification Window take one columns because you don't set colspan

[image]

you must add colspan="3" to your td of notfication

```
 <td  colspan="3" style=" ">
        <asp:TextBox CssClass="inputBoxes"  ID="txtBox_NotificationWindow" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
```

Comment: problem is not notification window is the fact on my computer the VERY first row alert name takes the same width as notification window I don't know why it is doing that

Comment: notification window only take that long is intended

Comment: be sure your browser not cache old html , 
delete history or press ctrl+f5 to reload your page

Comment: and what is the class="FormFormatTable"

Comment: sorry about that I deleted that css already because I feared it could meddle with my css so it is no longer present so it is not doing anything

Comment: I updated my screenshot on my screen and uploaded it onto the question seems different with yours and I just refreshed my cache so I don't know why it is doing this

Comment: what browser you use?
try to open your html page in different browser

Comment: I am using latest version of chrome

Comment: no IE is doing the same thing whyy???? what am I forgetting or what is causing this ?? because it is acting as if it is not reading the css at all just reading the page itself. that is what I noticed and  I inspect element on the table and it showed clearly that the css is been applied expect it is not

Comment: mmmm , how you add the css on your page
you must add on header like this



 <style>
.inputBoxes {
    width: 100%;
}
    </style>

Comment: let me try add this in manually on the asp.net page itself instead of css

Comment: nope still doesn't work I am very frustrated because this seem really straight forward and IT WORKS ON JS FIDDLE!!! but not in the actual page :(

Comment: to test if style is applyed try to add color like this <td colspan="3" style="  background-color:Red;">

Comment: And be sure you don't disable CSS in browser , and sure there no code ( javascript or vb code ) that change styles

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra quote in the following line (the cell definition that contains your *ddl_Severity* control).

```
<td style=" height: 60px"" >
```

Maybe remove this quote, and see if that fixes it.